# Android ActionBar Menu Icons not appearing

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

Before you Tag as a duplicate question: I've read:

[Action buttons doesn't show up on Action Bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512644/action-buttons-doesnt-show-up-on-action-bar)

[Action Bar not showing action view icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099221/action-bar-not-showing-action-view-icons)

and

[Android: Icons don't appear in Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625239/android-icons-dont-appear-in-action-bar)

But the issue is not resolved. My action bar will only hold the menu items in the overflow. I cannot get the icons to appear on the action bar itself.

The code for my menu is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/homeIcon"
    android:title="@string/Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always" /></menu>
```

I have declared the support header files but it hasn't made a difference. 
I tried replacing the word 'app' in "app:showAsAction" with my app name as it appears in @strings but it will not accept it because the app name has white space.

it is called my App instead of myApp.

Is there that the reason why i can't get any icons in my actionBar, if yes is there a way to resolve it.. without recreating my app? i tried changing the name in @strings and that didn't resolve the issue, so it could just as easily be something else.

Thanks in advance community!

Comment: Can you post your Activity code? If you not, check if you have  onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Thanks I've edited the question to include the activity

Comment: Search for Slidenerd in youtube, he did in video what you want to do. Don't worry, he is not the type of guy that do the tutorials for the viewer to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not using AppCompat (or not using it in this particular situation) then `android:showAsAction`. Yes, Android Studio will complain and recommend to use `app:showAsAction` but it works.